# Do Hyperledger platforms have full/light-weighted nodes like Ethereum?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ethereum

I'm new to Blockchain and trying to understand if Hyperledger platforms (such as Fabric and Sawtooth) offer full/light nodes separation like Ethereum.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about STL, but Fabric doesn't have a light node.

There are 2 reasons for this:

1) The hash in the block header is simply a concatenated hash over the block data, and not a Merkle tree root. So you cannot prove efficiently that a Transaction exists in a block, without giving the entire block.

2) Unlike most Blockchains, Fabric is an execute-order Blockchain, which means that some transactions in the block may not be valid at all, and only at the time of commit, the peer checks if they are valid.

Comment: Thank you vey much, I'm working on an academic seminar and that's helpful. I'm still looking for the answer about Sawtooth.

Comment: Then you can perhaps ask in https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/sawtooth