# Does Hyperledger Fabric use a Merkle tree for the block data hash?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, merkle-tree

I found multiple sources that are not precise enough for me to be sure. They seemingly disagree ever so slightly.

I need to know that, because I would like to proof the inclusion of a transaction to a client without revealing the actual content of other transactions. If that is possible.

I looked into the source of the likely responsible function [BlockDataHash](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/9e416d58eb423c04491d3026f2b2937a1e9220c0/protoutil/blockutils.go#L65). It seems to just concatenate a data array containing the byte arrays of each transaction. But I'm not sure if that is the actual function used, nor do I know if this "Data" array contains the whole transaction or some hash thereof (maybe this "Merkle Tree Query Summary" in the proposal response part of the transaction).

The [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.4/config_update.html?highlight=merkle#channel) doesn't solve it quite either. It refers to a Merkle tree which is so wide that it "corresponds to a simple flat hash of the concatenation of block data bytes". But I see no implementation of this Merkle tree in the source.

Lastly, I stumbled upon this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59697490) by @yacovm. Which mentions that it is some concatenated hash. But there was a non efficient way to prove inclusion without handing out the entire block. But maybe this is referring to some construction with zero knowledge proofs.

Comment: According to [the link you provided](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.4/config_update.html?highlight=merkle#channel), the Fabric's Merkle tree is a very wide 4294967295-ary tree. It's [technically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree#Overview) still a Merkle tree, but it will never have a second level and is practically the same as a hash of concatenated data.

Comment: But what happens if I got some larger block data? Or is that impossible?

Comment: I suppose the value (approx. 4e9) means 4e9 leaf nodes, i.e. 4e9 transactions, which is huge (also, there is number of transactions limit in a block in Orderer config section). Even if it's just 4e9 bytes that would mean a block of over 4GiB in size, which might be possible, but unlikely to happen in practice.